# How can I left align a set of check boxes?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to show a group of 8 check boxes in 2 columns with labels on the right side of the boxes and they are aligning center. I want them to left align but cant seem to get them to work. Included is a small bit of the form.

```
<h5 class="text-center">Please check all ares of interest</h5>
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-check col-lg-6">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value="Managed Services" id="msp">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="msp">Managed Services</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check col-lg-6">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value="Tech Support" id="support">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="support">Tech Support</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS. I have tried adding text-left and also adding another class and neither have worked.

```
body {
    background-image: url("../img/bg4.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
header {
    margin: 25px 0px;
}
hr {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}
hr.light {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
section {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #222;
}
/* MISC */
.logo {
    color: #ED1B34;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.5em;
}
.company {
    color: #4B4E56;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 2.5em;
}
.slogan {
    color: #0d0f12;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.left {
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
}
.fa-heart {
    color: red;
}
.form-check {
    padding-right: .9rem;
}
.form-error {
    color: red;
}
.form-success {
    color: green;
    font-size: 120%;
}
div.form-group label {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.form-check-label {
    font-size: 85%;
}
.form-check {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Please also provide your CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default *bootstrap* style has center justify-content for `.form-inline .form-check` on small breakpoint and up. That's why the checkbox and label inside `.form-check` is aligned center:

```css
@media (min-width: 576px)
    .form-inline .form-check {
        display: flex;
        ...
        justify-content: center;
        ...
    }
```

There are so many ways to left align the check boxes. The following is one:

```html
<h5 class="text-center">Please check all ares of interest</h5>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value="Managed Services" id="msp">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="msp">Managed Services</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value="Tech Support" id="support">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="support">Tech Support</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would still recommend to wrap the columns with `.row` whenever you use columns. And you don't have to use `.form-inline` to line up check boxes in line in smaller screens. You can use `.col-auto`, which will set the width to auto.

Personally I would use `.row` and `.col-*` to setup the structure/grid I need, and then I put elements inside the grid. It's just my personal preference.

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/7qfLcko1/5/